# Find and change images and css in a specific container

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok,

i have this: somewhere on the page:

```
<a href="http://www.brand-mark.de/brandimpact/">
<i class="menu_icon fa blank"></i>
<span class="menu-text">
<img width="174" height="49" title="XYZ" alt="XYZ" src="http://www.xyz.png">
<noscript><img width="174" height="49" title="XYZ" alt="XYZ" src="http://www.xyz.png"><noscript>
</span>
</a>
```

and have to replace everything inside "span class="menu-text"" (the img and noscript tags)

with something else like:

```
<span class="menu-text">
<img width="200" height="100" title="newtitle" alt="newalt" src="newsrc.png">
<noscript><img width="200" height="100" title="newtitle" alt="newalt" src="newsrc.png"></noscript>
</span>
</a>
```

How do i do that in jQuery on page load?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Use `.replaceWith()`

Comment: use $(".menu-text").empty() to remove all the childs then create what you want dynamically in jquery

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dkxfc71L/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use this

```
$(function(){
    $('.menu-text img')
    .attr('src','newsrc.png')
    .attr('alt','newalt')
    .attr('title','newtitle');
    $('.menu-text noscript').html($('.menu-text img').clone());
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/40fhjhcL/)

Comment: much apprecciated!